# How can I apply a new Cypher on the results of a previous cypher

Tags: algorithm, neo4j, cypher

I am looking for one or several entities in neo4j using cypher to draw a graph on the screen, to which the end user will decide which algorithm he wants to apply. That is, I want to apply algorithms on the result obtained previously.

For example: I have this query:

```
MATCH (e)<-[r]->(a) 
WHERE id(e) IN [9336,9306,9352,5215,9354] 
RETURN e,r,a
```

This returns a result, which one I can draw the graph on the screen. But now I need to apply an algorithm to the previous graph, so that the result is preserved but now I throw the degree of centrality of each node in the graph.

For example I want to apply this:

```
CALL algo.pageRank.stream('', '', {iterations:20, dampingFactor:0.85, concurrency:4}) YIELD nodeId, score
```

But over the previous result.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j doesn't have a way to feed the results of a cypher that has returned directly into the start of another query, but there are a few things you can do.

**Rerun the previous query, replacing  RETURN with WITH**

So in your example, run

```
MATCH (e)<-[r]->(a) 
WHERE id(e) IN [9336,9306,9352,5215,9354] 
RETURN e,r,a
```

followed by

```
MATCH (e)<-[r]->(a) 
WHERE id(e) IN [9336,9306,9352,5215,9354] 
WITH e,r,a
CALL algo.pageRank.stream('', '', {iterations:20, dampingFactor:0.85, concurrency:4}) YIELD nodeId, score
RETURN e,r,a, nodeId, score
```

This has the side effect though of if the results of a previous query changes (because nodes where added/removed, the results will be updated to reflect the newer data. (Can be good or bad depending on your perspective)

**Rematch the results of the last query for the start of your next one**

I wouldn't recommend this. This will be painful to implement, but is possible.